# Python - list 2 columns from excel file as list but alternate between values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file and have 2 columns that I would like to convert to a list. I want to alternate between the columns, so it would be like this:

"F1,O1,F2,O2,F3,O3....."

whats the best way using python? I have read the columns as df, and when i ask for list it just shows the headers.

```
#read profles excel ss, column O and drop all Nan cells
import pandas
path=r"Profiles.xlsx"
df = pandas.read_excel(path,usecols="F,O").dropna(how="all")
print(list(df))
```

This just shows "Header F, Header O"

Probably very simple but im new to python and learning :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with list comprehension, as mentioned in another another
A simple for loop can also do the trick that you can understand easily.

Here is a sample on how that can be done:

```
a = list(range(1, 10, 2))
b = list(range(2,11, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B'])
df['A'] = a
df['B'] = b
df
```

The sample dataframe created would be something like this:

```
    A   B
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   5   6
3   7   8
4   9   10
```

This is the for loop you want to run to get the desired result:

```
res = []
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    res.append(r['A'])
    res.append(r['B'])
print(res)
```